# WinHttp verify peer and server and ssl callback

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ssl, libcurl, winhttp

I need some alternative to following libcurl functions in WinHttp.

```
curl_easy_setopt(cURLHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, vP);
curl_easy_setopt(cURLHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, vH);
```

and

```
curl_easy_setopt(cURLHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION, sslctxfun);
```

and

```
curl_easy_setopt(cURLHandle, CURLOPT_CAINFO, cPath);
```

Till now, I guess that `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` are automatically taken care by WinHttp and always set to true - but how to turn them false?

For `CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION` I couldn't find any equivalent callback.

For `CURLOPT_CAINFO` I guess following should work.

```
WinHttpSetOption(iCURLHandle, WINHTTP_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_ISSUER_LIST, path, MAX_PATH_LENGTH);
```

I'm a novice in WinHttp. Please help. Thanks